# How do I get a field from json object in Azure Data Explorer

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I use this kql to query in Azure :
ContainerLog | where LogEntry contains "ReportProcessTime"
|project LogEntry

to get the LogEntry like :

2022-05-30 09:00:04.216 INFO 1 --- [io-8080-exec-10] c.t.s.r.s.ReportManagementService : [METRIC] [ReportProcessTime] {"totalProcessingTime":3188,"generatingTime":3188,"tryCount":1,"generatorProcessingTime":15552000000}

and we'd like to get value of the field "totalProcessingTime" ,which is 3188  in order to evaluate the performance.

however we tried with parse_json but not work.

Comment: Why would you expect text which is clearly not in JSON format to be parsed successfully as JSON?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [parse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/parseoperator) operator to get the json part

P.S.
Prefer [has_cs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/has-cs-operator) over [contains](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/contains-operator).
See [Query best practices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/best-practices)

```
print LogEntry = '2022-05-30 09:00:04.216 INFO 1 --- [io-8080-exec-10] c.t.s.r.s.ReportManagementService : [METRIC] [ReportProcessTime] {"totalProcessingTime":3188,"generatingTime":3188,"tryCount":1,"generatorProcessingTime":15552000000}'
| where LogEntry has_cs "ReportProcessTime" 
| parse LogEntry with * "[ReportProcessTime] " myjson:dynamic
| extend tolong(myjson.totalProcessingTime)
```

| LogEntry | myjson | myjson_totalProcessingTime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-05-30 09:00:04.216 INFO 1 --- [io-8080-exec-10] c.t.s.r.s.ReportManagementService : [METRIC] [ReportProcessTime] {"totalProcessingTime":3188,"generatingTime":3188,"tryCount":1,"generatorProcessingTime":15552000000} | {"totalProcessingTime":3188,"generatingTime":3188,"tryCount":1,"generatorProcessingTime":15552000000} | 3188 |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA22PQUsDMRCF74L/YcilKmZJtq6sAU%20lQsGq1N6WpYR02I10kyUZbRf1v9u1otJ2YC7vfTO81wbrCO59NXYUOriFQSrSlIuMDwWIGyWEEldJKq9h8nD3CBI451BYz3ORC44bNFyKEkxCSUzCdmfY%20kBT7XSFDTp6xvBmDYKCYjqezyajEood8xS8wRjntsES3hl50qsfzbqql5kayjy/ZBU6DJr21G3ekX91xJT8RXzY/yCzLEvF93wOTk8%20YF1jwL/GtY4LE4EdZGLQ060O8R%209tlTDBbBjFRg03Uv0Ti07pxtr%20nPcELolkF95V53t/ORI0/Mv9O2rX4gBAAA=)

Comment: Thank you for answering . It works . And what other way can get this processingtime value if not use parse as you said it is not in json format?

Comment: The whole log is not in JSON format, only the suffix is, therefore this is what can be converted to JSON, as I did in my answer by stating in the parse operaor that myjson is of type dybsnic. If you have another scenario, please open a new post for it